# Assigning output of a command to a variable(BASH)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I need to assign the output of a command to a variable. The command I tried is:

```
grep UUID fstab | awk '/ext4/ {print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0,6)}'
```

I try this code to assign a variable:

```
UUID=$(grep UUID fstab | awk '/ext4/ {print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0,6)}')
```

However, it gives a syntax error. In addition I want it to work in a bash script.

The error is:

```
./upload.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token ENE=$( grep UUID fstab | awk '/ext4/ {print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0,6)}'
 )'

./upload.sh: line 12:   ENE=$( grep UUID fstab | awk '/ext4/ {print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0,6)}'
 )'
```

Comment: What is the exact error, and are you sure you are using `bash`? Looks fine to me.

Comment: This is (presumably) not related to whatever error you're seeing, but -- your whole pipeline can be written as the single command `awk '/UUID/ && /ext4/ { print substr($1, 6) }' fstab`.

Comment: You have an extra single quote at the end of what you copy-pasted as your error message (which differs from what you included above).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

well, using the '$()' subshell operator is a common way to get the output of a bash command. As it spans a subshell it is not that efficient.

I tried :

```
UUID=$(grep UUID /etc/fstab|awk '/ext4/ {print $1}'|awk '{print substr($0,6)}')
echo $UUID # writes e577b87e-2fec-893b-c237-6a14aeb5b390
```

it works perfectly :)

EDIT:

Of course you can shorten your command :

```
# First step : Only one awk
UUID=$(grep UUID /etc/fstab|awk '/ext4/ {print substr($1,6)}')
```

Once more time :

```
# Second step : awk has a powerful regular expression engine ^^
UUID=$(cat /etc/fstab|awk '/UUID.*ext4/ {print substr($1,6)}')
```

You can also use awk with a file argument ::

```
# Third step : awk use fstab directlty
UUID=$(awk '/UUID.*ext4/ {print substr($1,6)}' /etc/fstab)
```

Comment: Ok, here is the issue:
It works at terminal. However, I want it to work in a script.

Comment: @ErayTuncer This is certainly due to a typo in your script.

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to pipe awk through awk. The grep is likely not needed either.

Comment: @jordanm : Yes of course, my point was to affect the OP command to a shell variable. I will add a shorter command if I have 5 seconds ^^

Answer (score 1):

Just for trouble-shooting purposes, and something else to try to see if you can get this to work, you could also try to use "backticks", e.g,

```
cur_dir=`pwd`
```

would save the output of the `pwd` command in your variable cur_dir, though using `$()` approach is generally preferable.

To [quote](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) from a pages given to me on http://unix.stackexchange.com:

> The second form `` `COMMAND` `` (using backticks) is more or less obsolete for Bash, since it
>   has some trouble with nesting ("inner" backticks need to be escaped)
>   and escaping characters. Use `$(COMMAND)`, it's also POSIX!

Comment: Is there actually a difference between `\`\`` and `$()`?

Comment: @Shahbaz There is, the `$()` will work better with nested constructs, while backticks will be more tricky. There was a discussion about this on http://unix.stackexchange.com, but I can't find it right now. I found it, I'll put it in my answer.

Comment: it's definitely more clear to nest using `$()`, but what I meant was is there an actual difference for bash? Do they behave differently? Or are they different syntaxes for the same thing?

Comment: Ok I just saw your update. Dang, I liked backticks, they are so easy to type.

Comment: @Shahbaz I usually use the backticks, they work for me, but I am mindful that if I do something more complex I may want to consider the alternatives.

Comment: The main difference between `$()` and backticks is that, unfortunately, there are still some shells in use that do not recognize `$()` syntax. (even though it has been standardized for over 20 years now!)  There is no difference in bash.